# Discover not connected to network device which has turn-on wi-fi

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

Let's say We have a room. In room there are three devices which have a turn-on wi-fi module but only two ware connected to network. So two device have access to Internet and one device still dosen't have any network, they have only turn on wi-fi module, and is ready to connected, but is not.
It is possible get some information on Linux about not connected device ?

Comment: You should be more specific about what you hope to achieve. You want "some information" about a device that is *not* connected to the network? If it's not connected, what do you hope to see?

Comment: For example MAC. How ? Device has a turn-on radio wi-fi, so may be exist some way send request to this radio wi-fi which is not connected to network ? Or may be not connected wi-fi module still send to some signal to oyher AP and this signal can be captured and we can get some information. I don't know what information I will can get, question is : wheter is possible get any information